# Is there an estimate of how many people infected with SARS-CoV-2 are asymptomatic?

Tags: covid-19

A week ago spanish soccer team returned from Milan and 1/3 of the team members have been tested positive for Coronavirus, but none of them developed symptoms. They yet could develop since the incubation period is said to be up to 2 weeks, but it's said for there is people who is asymptomatic during the whole disease.

Is there an estimate of how many people infected with SARS-CoV-2 are asymptomatic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"data to date suggest that 80% of infections are mild or asymptomatic, 15% are severe infection, requiring oxygen and 5% are critical infections, requiring ventilation."

[image]

https://www.who.int/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/situation-reports/20200306-sitrep-46-covid-19.pdf?sfvrsn=96b04adf_2

Comment: I guess in the middle or 80% there is something like having fever but not requiring oxygen? Or not?

Comment: Sure. Fever is a mild response experienced by most

Comment: Too bad they didnt differentiate yet between those you can spot because they have fever and those we don't even know they have the virus, that way we would be able to estimate how many people in total are around infected with the virus and capable of infecting others